# 'Go Back' in browser lose the data in form

Tags: javascript

I have a display area where grabs the information entered in a textarea, and the display area will hyperlink to a page. However, when I use the 'Go Back' function in browser, the information that has been entered in the textarea remains, while the text in the display area are removed. How this can be changed? Thanks very much!

```
    <script>    
    function replacetext(){
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
        }                   
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <p>Text</p>
    <form><textarea id="input" onKeyUp="replacetext();" onKeyPress="replacetext();"></textarea></form><br>
    <a id="test" href="http://www.google.com/">
    <div id="output"></div>
    </a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page load you need to also run that function. We'll wrap the check in a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event to avoid any input filling browser delays.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    replacetext();
}, false);
```